# checkbox value within submit button

Tags: javascript, html, button, checkbox, input

So this is tough to describe but I cannot figure it out, I feel like i am close however!

Basically I have a list of things, that need to be organised.

lets pretend its books, I have all these books, with all the information on them (author, length, title, genre). If I wanted to search my array of books specifically for comedic books. I would tick the comedy tickbox and hit search.

I have gotten this to work easily! the tricky part is that I would like it to search straight away when it is selected, however my javascript searches through checkboxes to see which checkboxes are selected before it runs my code that eliminates the answers that are irrelevant. so it needs to be a checkbox value that is submitted.

Is there a way I can have an image that functions as a button, that carries a value of a checkbox...???

so far I have gotten this close:

```
<div class="wells">
    <input type="image" value="comedy" src="img/pieces/comedy.png"
           alt="comedy" onclick="myFunction()" checked>
</div>
```

I know myFunction works and does what it is told.
I literally need the value of the checkbox to be used as a submit button.

the long way is like this:

```
<img class="imgcomedy" src="img/pieces/comedy.png"> :
<input type="checkbox" class="roundedOne" name="comedy" value="comedy">
```

then the user would scroll to the submit button and hit send, sending the value of the checkbox to the function myFunction().

I know myFunction works and does what it is told.
I literally need the value of the checkbox to be used as a submit button.

Comment: no one has time to read story. be clear and crisp about your problem. I am too lazy to read this

Comment: Are you going to allow more than one checkbox to be checked at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

You can give image which behaves as checkbox, when you click on submit it gives values like true.or false for that check box.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution, depending on what your actual requirements are...
You can use a `<button>` instead of a checkbox; the contents of a button are fully customizable with essentially any HTML...

```
<button type="submit" class="roundedOne" name="comedy" value="comedy">
    <img class="imgcomedy" src="img/pieces/comedy.png">
</button>
```

You may want this as a submit button, and/or attach a javascript click-handler.

If you need several categories chosen together, such as *"list things in either category drama or comedy"* which you can do with checkboxes, you have several options.
You could also include a checkbox but keep it hidden, and then check/uncheck it by using your click-handler attached to the button.
You could keep an `<input type="hidden" value="">` field and set the value in your click-handler, adding and removing categories; for example
      initial: value=""
      after clicking the *comedy* button: value="comedy"
      after clicking the *dramay* button: value="comedy,drama"
      after clicking the *comedy* button again: value="drama"

Comment: `code`
<div class="wells"><img class="imgcomedy" src="img/pieces/comedy.png">

&nbsp;:&nbsp;

<button type="submit" class="roundedOne" name="comedy" value="comedy" onclick="myFunction()">
<input type="checkbox" class="roundedOne spacingcb" name="comedy" value="comedy">
</button></div>
 `code`

Comment: Is the code i used in the end. It just has a button with a checkbox within it. when ticked it submits and searches!